# как сохранять вкладки google-chrome ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, google-chrome

Можно ли установить какой нибудь плагин, чтоб перед закрытием хрома вкладки сохранялись, а при следующей сессии предлагалось их открыть?

У меня выскакивает такое предложение только в том случае, если ноут экстренно выключился и при следующем запуске предлагается восстановить вкладки, но если я сам закрываю хром, то приходиться все ссылки на важные вкладки сохранять где то... это очень неудобно...

Comment: 1) открываем `chrome://settings/` и там выбираем *При запуске открывать* -> *ранее открытые вкладки* 2) если это не устроит (у меня были проблемы с восстановлением при экстренном выключении компа), посмотрите на [Session Buddy](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/session-buddy/edacconmaakjimmfgnblocblbcdcpbko), может пригодится

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Заходишь в настройки (меню справа вверху, после чего - настройки).
После чего кликаешь на настройки ещё раз, если не открылись, и под надписью "При запуске открывать" ставишь переключатель на "Ранее открытые вкладки".

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]